# Create a self kill iFrame by jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I like to create an iframe for an url by jQuery, and self-kill (remove, delete) the iframe after N seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to remove it after a given amount of seconds.

```
$(function () {
    $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" src="myUrl">').appendTo('body');

    // Remove it after 20 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
       $("#myFrame").remove();
    }, 20000);
});
```